# modify the clipString behavior in SwingUtilities

Tags: java, swing, swingutilities

When your text is truncated due to length in TableCellRenderer, it is abbreviated by a method called clipString in SwingUtilties2. How does one write some kind of custom clipping method? For instance, i would like to clip from the right instead

e.g.

A really long text

... long text

Answer (score 2):

Don't know that you can modify the behaviour of the SwingUtilities2 class.

> i would like to clip from the right instead

I think you mean you would like to see the dots on the left instead of the right.

If so, then you can create a custom renderer. Check out the [Left Dot Renderer](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/12/left-dot-renderer/)